# pyson, malformed node or string with literal_eval

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using `repr()` and `ast.literal_eval()` as an alternative to `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()`.

A simple `ast.literal_eval(repr(m))`, where `m` is a plain `dict()` full of `str()`, others `dict()` or `set()` objects only, fails with the error :

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7fe3eae74240>
```

How can I debug this, and get more information on the Error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set()` are perfectly valid `ast.literal_eval()` entries unless they are empty!

An empty `set()` will be represented as a constructor, since there is no dedicated literal (`{}` is an empty `dict()`), and the constructor can not be evaluated.

I will try to adapt the hook found here : https://gist.github.com/philipbjorge/5166022